# Overwrite environment variables with monkeypatch in pytest

Tags: python, environment-variables, pytest, monkeypatching

Currently, I have a file which contains

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=False, future=True)
```

Now, I would like to overwrite DATABASE_URL with monkeypatch in pytest, but sadly whatever I tried it stocked to the "old" values.

Do you have an idea how I can do it?

Comment: Can you please share where you are attempting to overwrite? Are you using monkeypatch.setenv()?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `create_async_engine()` call to use the monkeypatched value of DATABASE_URL?

Comment: @MadisonCourto Exactly I used it to overwrite it, but without success.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, that is the intention.

Comment: Then instead of monkeypatching `DATABASE_URL`, just monkeypatch `engine`.  Unless some other top-level variable uses engine, then you'd have to monkeypatch that one also... It quickly gets very messy.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better solution to simply modify the environment before importing that module, instead of monkeypatching:

```
import os

os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'some other value'

# os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL") will now return the new value
import mymodule
```

Monkeypatching is really intended to modify *behavior* (i.e. functions), not the *environment*.

Comment: That looks like a good solution and I manage to create and overwrite new env variables, but apparently, I cannot overwrite an existing env variable.

Comment: @tobias You should be able to overwrite existing variables. Can you show the code you're using?